# Flask-paginate is showing all results on one page

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, pagination

I am trying to set up a pagination for the products page, like this

```
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter

...

page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)

per_page = 4
offset = (page) * 10

search = False
q = request.args.get('q')
if q:
    search = True


pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, offset=offset, total=len(products), 
search=search, record_name='products')

return render_template('products.html', form=form, products=products, 
subcategories=subcategories, pagination=pagination)
```

while 'products' are fetched from a previous request in the code

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM products")
products = cur.fetchall()
```

However, on my products page I am getting back all of the products in the database (20 currently), while I can see that `{{ pagination.info }}` is showing "Displaying 1-4 products in total 20".

Also `{{ pagination.links }}` is working correctly, as it is showing functional pagination links, but still all of the products are visible on the page. Do you have any hints how this can be solved?

Thanks

Comment: Pagination without `ORDER BY` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll have that in mind, once I find the solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this one. Maybe is not the best one out there, and if you know better way to do that, please let me know. For now, I have solved this in the following way:

```
# Creating a cursor
cur = conn.cursor()

# Setting page, limit and offset variables
per_page = 4
page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
offset = (page - 1) * per_page

# Executing a query to get the total number of products
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM products")
total = cur.fetchall()

# Executing a query with LIMIT and OFFSET provided by the variables above
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY added_on DESC LIMIT %s OFFSET %s", (per_page, offset))
products = cur.fetchall()

# Closing cursor
cur.close()

...

# Setting up the pagination variable, where you are using len(total) to set the total number of 
# items available
pagination = Pagination(page=page, per_page=per_page, offset=offset, total=len(total), 
record_name='products')

# Render template, where you pass "products" variable
# for the prepared query with LIMIT and OFFSET, and passing "pagination" variable as well.
return render_template('products.html', form=form, products=products, pagination=pagination)
```